# Fields E300 error with django threadedcomments

Tags: django, threaded-comments

I am trying to install this module django-threadedcomments from this github https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments. But when I run migrate I get the following error. Note: I'm using Django 1.7 and django_comments is also installed.

> CommandError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS: threadedcomments.ThreadedComment.comment_ptr: (fields.E300)
>   Field defines a relation with model 'Comment', which is either not
>   installed, or is abstract

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'threadedcomments',
    'django_comments',
    'django.contrib.sites',
)

COMMENTS_APP = 'threadedcomments'
```

Comment: Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

pip install django-threadedcomments==1.0b1

As you see on [a link](https://github.com/HonzaKral/django-threadedcomments/issues/64), you would have no problem with beta version